# how to create a new column based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

Thank you for answering first. I want to combine the address and postcode if the condition is 0, and combine the address and postcode and 1 if the condition is 1. I tried the following, but the desired result does not come out. I would like to ask if the data type is a problem. Please give me a lot of advice.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('./address.csv')
data['full address'] = np.where(data['condition']='0', data['address']+'-'+data['postcode'], data['address']+'-'+data['postcode']+'-'+data['condition'])
```

**output**

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

**expected output**

[image: expected output]

Comment: `data['condition']=='0'`

Comment: Thank you but, it shows [TypeError: invalid type comparison]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [@quang-hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) in the comments, the syntax is incorrect. Also, remove the single quotes from 0 if the column datatype is int. You need the `==` for checking equality.

Please note that the `np.where` function as written will also output `data['address']+'-'+data['postcode']+'-'+data['condition']` whenever  `data['condition']` is not equal to 0.  It's essential an if-then-else clause.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('./address.csv')
data['full address'] = np.where(
    data['condition']== 0, 
    data['address']+'-'+data['postcode'], 
    data['address']+'-'+data['postcode']+'-'+data['condition']
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved it with the following code. However, I wonder if there is any way to solve the condition without changing the condition(int64) to str.                                 
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np                                                                                                           
   data = data.astype('str')
data = pd.read_csv('./address.csv')
data['full address'] = np.where(
    data['condition']== '0', 
    data['address']+'-'+data['postcode'], 
    data['address']+'-'+data['postcode']+'-'+data['condition']
    )`

Comment: what is the datatype for data['condition']?